# how to reload page after any function another user defined in javascript is executed

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, synchronous

I want to execute a function callback in my code but I have no idea if the function the user inputs is going to be synchronous or asynchronous and immediately after it's done I wish to reload the page.

So to simplify the example in the init options of my object, another user can pass a function like this

```
myObject.init(
    {
       js: function (){
           //sync or async code 
       }
    }
)
```

And it will get executed when init is invoked

```
class myObject{
   init: function(options){
        //amongst other things, execute js function then reload the page  
   }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to refresh the page after a JS function runs? The whole point of a JS function is to alter something on the page, usually (unless it sends an AJAX to the server or something). So why would you want to destroy that immediately afterwards? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you explain the context more fully?

Comment: Well it's for GDPR reasons and to handle when the user revokes his consent from some unknown scripts. When the user revokes his consent it's not enough to just delete the cookies. Some scripts do not store any cookies but still send data once they're triggered. In order to undo their actions and manipulations in the DOM I need to reload the page.

Comment: Unknown in the context that I have no previous knowledge what the other developers are going to put there. And so I want to give the developer that consumes the service I'm creating the ability to clean up his code and disable reload or to reload the page and also the ability to store in async way the consent log. So the code he enters may be synchronous plain cleanup or do something async then reload.

Comment: "still send data once they're triggered. In order to undo their actions"....if they've already sent data by that point, you can't undo that! But yes I take your general point.

Comment: Anyway I think if this is a tool for developers where they need to add certain functionality, then I think you need to decide how you want it to work, then clearly document how the developer must implement it in order for their code to be compatible with yours. e.g. If you want to support asynchronous stuff, then maybe you should require that the developer's code returns a Promise. (Then even if the dev's code is synchronous, they can still return an empty Promise just to satisfy your requirement)...

Comment: The key word here is revoke. They have already given consent once, scripts have ran by this time normally but when they revoke it, the scripts need to stop doing what they were doing :)

Comment: ...I don't think you can write code which can deal with any and all unknown behaviour. You need to define the interface between the two pieces of code - yours and the developer's. That's how most libraries etc make things work. They don't try to second-guess how other developers will implement their part, instead they define what info they require in order to interact correctly.